# Laravel multiple where clause in a whereHas constrain on a hasMany relationship

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following query...

```
$pgcs = PrivateGuard::with(['licences', 'state'])
        ->whereHas('licences', function($query){
          $query->whereDate('expiration_of_licence', '<', Carbon::today())
                ->where('renewal', 0);
        })
        ->where('status', 1)
        ->get();
```

I want to get $pgcs with licences that fulfill the above conditions, the whereDate works correctly, but where('renewal', 0) doesn't seem to work correctly.
The above query gets $pgcs with licences that have renewal that is = 1 as well, although same $pgc also have licences with renewal value of 0 and another with 1, I don't want a $pgc that has any licence with renewal value of 1 to be retrieved in this query. what do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your cases are

- [1] pgc .. has two or more licences with renewal 0 , 1
- [2] pgc .. has two or more licences with renewal 0 , 0
- [3] pgc .. has two or more licences with renewal 1 , 1

right now your query is getting pgcs for cases [1],[2]

so you have to alter your query logic a little, to only get [2]

```
$pgcs = PrivateGuard::with(['licences', 'state'])
        ->whereHas('licences', function($query){
          $query->whereDate('expiration_of_licence', '<', Carbon::today())
                ->where('renewal', 0);
        })
        ->whereDoesntHave('licences', function($query){
          $query->where('renewal', 1);
        })
        ->where('status', 1)
        ->get();
```

Comment: Wow! and I've been busting my ass on this issue since morning... Thanks Ahmed, it worked like charm.